# Unclear step in a textbook trigonometric identity proof

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

This is a step in the proof of a trigonometric identity:
$$\frac {1+cos\left(\frac {\pi}{2}-a\right)}{1-cos\left(\frac {\pi}{2}-a\right)}=\frac {2\cos^2\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac a2\right)}{2\sin^2\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac a2\right)}$$

Could you give me a hint on how this transformation was accomplished?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\cos2A=\cos^2A-\sin^2A=2\cos^2A-1=1-2\sin^2A$$